# Simple Graph database

Tags: graph, graph-databases, breadth-first-search

I know about Neo4j, RedisGraph, DGraph, ArangoDB.

But I don't want a so heavy client/server application. I just need to load 4 millions nodes and 10 millions relationships and request for the shortest path between 2 nodes. The graph in unweighted and not directed.

I wrote a Go code that can do the job in memory within 2 seconds on my laptop with the BFS algorithm. But I don't have to re-invent the wheel. I can't actually do it in a few milliseconds like Neo4j for example.

Is there an open source project for this ?

Comment: Are you needing to store the graph persistently? Ability to update it over time?  Or is this purely an occasionally "one off" calculation where reloading the graph each time is sufficient?

Comment: actully the database is fixed. I don't need to update nodes or edges. So this should be persistent. Or I could load it in memory at start.

Answer (score 2):

If all you're doing is calculating bidirectional shortest-path, you may not need a full graph database for this.  I would suggesting looking at existing graph libraries that can quickly load your graph into memory and that have built-in functions for shortest-path.  Examples are things like:

- https://networkx.programmingpedia.net/
- https://igraph.org/
- https://graph-tool.skewed.de/

A graph database is going to provide you with persistence, but is going to come with a trade-off of maintaining the database and perhaps needing to learn how to leverage the query language supported by that graph database. Graph databases are great for continual updates of the graph or performing more custom queries/path look-ups.